# Ionic browser camera position

Tags: css, cordova, ionic-framework, camera, ionic3

I have created a simple Ionic 3 application and it uses the [Camera](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/) Cordova plugin. When running `ionic cordova run browser` the camera plugin works but its positioned in the lower left quadrant of the window without any relation to ion-content. What is the best way to position the camera? Should it be set to absolute and position it relative to the window?